# phpExcel not able to process worksheet v2.1

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a problem in reading and displaying excel using phpExcel.
the excel worksheet version is 2.1, and only this version have the issue.

Please help.

Comment: What is the problem? What happens?

Comment: Excel 2.1 ???? do you really mean that? What is worksheet v2.1 and exactly what errors are you getting?

Comment: the data read using phpExcel is not displaying correctly. And this happens only with older version of excel file (v2.1)

Answer (score 2):

> the data read using phpExcel is not
>   displaying correctly. And this happens
>   only with older version of excel file
>   (v2.1)

Excel v2.1 is nearly 25 years old now (released in 1987), and is not supported by PHPExcel. The file structure for all Office files has evolved quite significantly over the years; and most Excel readers, including PHPExcel, only read files from version 5 (released in 1993) and which saw a major reorganisation of the file structure to the OLE2 compound document format.

You might be able to read an Excel BIFF2 file using COM; but you're likely to find that very few 3rd party libraries in any language support an Excel format that old.

Alternatively, read the file using MS Excel itself, and save it in a more recent version of the BIFF format before trying to read it into PHP.

**EDIT**

As a third option, it would also be possible to write an Excel2 Reader for PHPExcel, although this would be a significant piece of work.

Comment: thanks @Mark Baker . Yes you are right, excel 2.1 is old version. Here the upload are done by normal people. That is why I posted a question here. I think I must check the file version first and must give the user a meaningful message.

Comment: I just built an Excel 2 reader, tell me if you're still interested, viMal.

Comment: @silkfire - if it's an Excel2 Reader that will work with PHPExcel, you could always contribute it to the project

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm not certain about how to go about to incorporate it into the juggernaught known as PHPExcel :) by the way did you never receive my email?

Comment: @silkfire - can't find anything in my mailbox, or in spam filters

Comment: @MarkBaker You replied to me, so it can't possibly be in the trash bin =S *"You've done a good job if you've managed it all in 5 months of work..."* August 9, 2013 (exactly one month ago, actually).

Comment: Found a couple of responses from codeplex (re. codepage 10008 and merge cells with borders

Comment: @MarkBaker Nah, I sent them to your email (lange-demo something)

Comment: @MarkBaker You found it? I just didn't know what your main email address is :) Have you read this Wikipedia article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_POI They call it the Dreadful Drawing Format. I can understand why ^^

Comment: @silkfire - If you are prepared to share and have me rip off anything usable into PHPExcel (credited of course), you can email it to me at the lange-demon something email address... I'll keep an eye on my mailbox so I don't miss it - you'll have my appreciation and thanks, if nothing else

Comment: I can do this when you're close to the release of PHPExcel 2.0

Comment: @silkfire I am also in a need to read legacy format excel files, do you still have the excel reader code? could you, please, post it somewhere online (e.g. pastebin)?

Comment: I can send it to your email if you want

Comment: @silkfire Please send it to daremy@inbox.lv . Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few inconsistencies with phpExcel and certain Excel versions. I had not problem using Excel5 for example for some of my templates and then that broke from one version to the next. I recommend you to work using the latest xlsx readers and writers when using PHPExcel if possible since these seem to be the most robust ones.

Answer (score 0):

Hay vimal you can use some other methods to read excel file

Hope these links will help you

http://phpexcelreader.sourceforge.net/

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpexcel/

Thanks

Comment: Do not support BIFF2.